# QGIS flowmapper migration arrows from origin X to destination X - possible?

Tags: qgis, flow-map

I have a question about QGIS with the Flowmapper plugin. I am trying to visualize some real estate data. I have data about consumers who are actively searching for housing and what I want to visualize is:

1. In which neighbourhood does the consumer currently live?
2. In which neighbourhood would the consumer like to find a home?

I have used QGIS to find neighbourhood centroids. After this I created an 80x80 matrix and plotted all the ''migration'' data using the Flowmapper plugin and everything worked out fine.

There is just one thing that I cannot visualize and that is: Consumers who would like to find a home in the same neighbourhood as they currently live in.

The Flowmapper plugin only seems to plot the migration arrows from neighbourhood X to all the other neighbourhoods but not from neighbourhood X to neighbourhood X.

Does anyone know if there is a way to visualize this? (preferably with Flowmapper)

Perhaps with a circular arrow that points from neighbourhood X back to neighbourhood X.

For a complete analysis I would very much like to know how consumers aim to move from one to another neighbourhood but also how many consumers are contempt with the current neighbourhood they live in and would like to find a new housing within this current neighbourhood.

Comment: You could try using rule-based symbology, representing those consumers who want to stay put with an svg marker that looks like the circular arrow you want.